# Iframe src will not load a .php form

Tags: php, iframe, http-status-code-404

I wanted to include a contact form to my website so I got an easy to use form here: http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/simple-php-contact-form.html (the middle one)

I followed the instructions and uploaded the 'Contact' folder (containing the contactform.php) to the root of my website.

I then chose a page on my site that I wanted the contact form to appear and inserted the following:

```
<iframe src="http://[my site].com/contact/contactform.php" frameborder='0' width='100%' height="600' allowtransparency='true'></iframe>
```

Now when I go to the page on my site that I expect to see the form I get an error '404 file or directory not found'.

Everything else on the page is OK but the form does not appear, what's wrong??

Comment: a typo, the 'Contact' folder is 'contact'

Answer (score 0):

> I followed the instructions and uploaded the '**Contact'** folder to the root of my website.

URLs are sometimes case-sensitive. Instead of

```
http://[my site].com/contact/contactform.php
```

you should use

```
http://[my site].com/Contact/contactform.php
```

Comment: If on Windows, no. If on LINUX, yes.